# Can I pass a parameter into a findbyid() function in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a variable *user* that I want to push into a *users* array in an Express update request.

```
router.put( '/projectUser/:id', function( req, res ) {
    var projectid = req.params.id;
    var users = req.body.project.users;
    var user = req.body.user;


    return ProjectProfile.findById( projectid, function( err, project, user ) {
        console.log(user);
        console.log(project);

        project.users.push(user); 

        return project.save( function( err ) {
            if( !err ) {
                console.log( 'Project Users updated' );
                return res.send( project );
            } else {
                console.log( err );
                return res.send('ERROR');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

In the example the variable user will be pushed into the users array as undefined as it is out of scope.

Is there anyway to pass the variable user as a parameter in a findById function?

Comment: Drop `user` from the `findById` callback arguments. It shouldn't be passed as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't perfectly understand the question, but I think you are trying to add the userId value (req.body.user) into the `users` (Array) property of the ProjectProfile model. Is that right?

If that's the case I believe your code should look something like this (I'm leaving aside validations, error checking, duplicate checking, etc. so use only as reference)

```
router.put('/projectUser/:id', function(req, res) {
  return ProjectProfile.findById(req.params.id, function(err1, project) {
    project.users.push(req.body.user);
    return project.save(function(err2) {
      return res.send('OK');
    });
  });
});
```

Please check the [Model#findById](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) docs, your `save()` callback takes 2 arguments, not 3.

Comment: Do check for errors and specially the existence of `project`, otherwise your app could crash.